# Can't print RDD content with take() action

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

When I try to print RDD content with `first()` action I am able to print it with foreach loop. But with `take()` action it doesn't print out content.

using first()

```
myRDD.first().foreach(println)
1
2013-07-25 00:00:00.0
11599
CLOSED
```

using take():

```
myRDD.take(5).foreach(println)
[Ljava.lang.String;@23a5818e
[Ljava.lang.String;@4715ae33
[Ljava.lang.String;@9fc9f91
[Ljava.lang.String;@1fac1d5c
[Ljava.lang.String;@108a46d6
```

I expect same output as first() indeed it should be. But ı get different output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your RDD is of type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]]`. In that case the return type of the `first` method is `Array[String]` and the `foreach(println)` prints the elements of the first string array in the RDD.
But the return type of `take(5)` is `Array[Array[String]]` and  `foreach(println)` prints the 5 elements.

To get the same output for `first` and `take(5)` either use

```
println(myRDD.first())
myRDD.take(5).foreach(println)
```

or

```
myRDD.first().foreach(println)
myRDD.take(5).foreach(_.foreach(println))
```